# Select SQL Query Not Working With Simple Where clouse

Tags: mysql, indexing, percona

Thee is one table Mysql Table On which simple sql where date = 'Some date' is not working

Have checked logs.
Reload the tables several times & tried.

#### This is proof that record exists :-

```
select * from TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY limit 1;

+------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+
| TRCD_DATE  | TRCD_SPREAD_START_DATE | TRCD_SPREAD_END_DATE | TRCD_SOURCE_CHENNEL_ID | TRCD_CIRCLE_ID | TRCD_CATALOUGE_ID | TRCD_CONTENT_ID | TRCD_SONG_CODE_ID | TRCD_YT_CP_POLICY_ID | TRCD_YT_CHANNEL_ID | TRCD_PRODUCT_NAME_ID | TRCD_TRXN_TYPE_ID | TRCD_TRXN_COUNT | TRCD_TOP_LINE | TRCD_REVENUE |
+------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+
| 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-01             | 2018-01-04           |                      5 |              1 |                 1 |          945723 |                 1 |                    1 |                  1 |                  211 |               180 |            1.75 |             0 |            0 |
+------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+
```

#### This is proof that index on date exists :-

```
select * from TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY limit 1;
CREATE TABLE `TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY` (
  `TRCD_DATE` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `TRCD_SPREAD_START_DATE` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `TRCD_SPREAD_END_DATE` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `TRCD_SOURCE_CHENNEL_ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TRCD_CIRCLE_ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TRCD_CATALOUGE_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TRCD_CONTENT_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TRCD_SONG_CODE_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TRCD_YT_CP_POLICY_ID` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TRCD_YT_CHANNEL_ID` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TRCD_PRODUCT_NAME_ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TRCD_TRXN_TYPE_ID` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TRCD_TRXN_COUNT` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TRCD_TOP_LINE` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TRCD_REVENUE` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `IDX_TRCD_DATE` (`TRCD_DATE`),
  KEY `IDX_TRCD_SOURCE_CHENNEL_ID` (`TRCD_SOURCE_CHENNEL_ID`),
  KEY `IDX_TRCD_CATALOUGE_ID` (`TRCD_CATALOUGE_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

#### This is the issue, it should give some count but its not coming (See 1st query result above data is present):-

```
select count(*) from TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY where TRCD_DATE='2018-01-01';

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

#### Proof that it is using index :-

```
explain select count(*) from TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY where TRCD_DATE='2018-01-01';
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                    | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY | ref  | IDX_TRCD_DATE | IDX_TRCD_DATE | 3       | const |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

#### Force index also not working :-

```
select count(*) from TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY FORCE INDEX(IDX_TRCD_DATE) where TRCD_DATE='2018-01-01';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

#### Yes, its huge table :-

```
select count(*) from TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY;
+------------+
| count(*)   |
+------------+
| 2006275044 |
+------------+
```

#### Table & Index Size :-

> 103G = TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY.MYD
>
> 52G = TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY.MYI

#### Surpriseingly this is working, but I can not use alway like this :-

```
select count(*) from TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY where date(TRCD_DATE)='2018-01-01';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1235523 |
+----------+
```

I know This is working because index will not come in account when using function on that indexed column.

#### Which Percona Server :-

> Server version: 5.5.60-38.12-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 38.12,
>   Revision 26ef816

#### Nothing comes in Error or warning mysql log when query is giving zero count.

Where clouse on other column on which there is index that is working properly.
Can someone help why its not working on that date column?
I want to add some more index on this table but this is not working so I am stopping here.

Comment: `<pet-peeve>`Get rid of the common prefix `TRCD_` - it clutters and makes things hard to read.`</pet-peeve>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Meanwhile, one of these should work.  (Go down the list until you get a usable table.  Most options are slow because they involve copying the table.)

- `CHECK TABLE TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY;` reports an error, do `REPAIR TABLE TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY;`.
- `OPTIMIZE TABLE TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY;`
- `REPAIR TABLE TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY USE_FRM;`
- `DROP INDEX ...` (for each index), then `ADD INDEX ...`
- copy table over:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
  INSERT INTO new SELECT * FROM TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY;
  RENAME TABLE TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY TO old,
        new TO TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY;
  DROP TABLE old;
  ```
- Restore from backup?

Those are things that are sometimes needed for MyISAM tables; InnoDB is more robust.

Comment: CHECK TABLE TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY;                                                                                                                            | TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY | check | error    | Key in wrong position at page 7670802432 |
| TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY | check | error    | Corrupt

So i did ran Repair & Optimize. Still my sql did not work.
So ran Check Table again & its still showing table Corrupt msg again.

Comment: Mysql Error log says this..
190505 21:25:11 [ERROR] Got an error from thread_id=35306, /mnt/workspace/percona-server-5.5-redhat-binary/label_exp/centos6-64/rpmbuild/BUILD/percona-server-5.5.60-38.12/storage/myisam/ha_myisam.cc:915
190505 21:25:11 [ERROR] MySQL thread id 35306, OS thread handle 0x7f154c543700, query id 141793517 localhost cubot Checking table

Whats to do now?

Comment: I can not convert table into InnoDB.
Its huge table so loading table will take my whole day. Whci is not affordable.

As we know mysql Error now. Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: @Punit - See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/repair-table.html - use `EXTENDED` or `USE_FRM`.  Either will take time.

Comment: I ran Repair table TRN_RP_CONSUMPTION_DAILY USE_FRM;
As suggested because its index related issue.

After that also my select did not work.
So ran  CHECK TABLE & its showing Corrupt again.

Comment: @Punit - I added all the options I could think of.  This repair task is taking longer than converting to InnoDB?

Comment: Thanks, But I have tried all the option what you have mention before posting my issue here.
Only InnoDB I have not tried because its workaround
Because its looks like some issue is something related to Indexing. So need some help on that.

Mysql Error log says this.
190505 21:25:11 [ERROR] Got an error from thread_id=35306, /mnt/workspace/percona-server-5.5-redhat-binary/label_exp/centos6-64/rpmbuild/BUILD/percona-server-5.5.60-38.12/storage/myisam/ha_myisam.cc:915

As we know now what error log says, but no idea how to fix this.

Comment: MyISAM is all-but-deprecated.  So you won't get any joy from filing a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried STR_TO_DATE MySQL function in your where clause?

**In your case:** TRCD_DATE = STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-01','%Y,%m,%d') (or inverse %m and %d)

For more information: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

I hope this answers to your problem/question.

Comment: Check my create TRCD_DATE is defined as date only.
No need to use any function.
Result should come without any use of function

Comment: Result of your query is null because you try to compare/match Date with String. Process to the convert with STR_TO_DATE and I guess that it will be fine. Have you tried?

Comment: No need for conversion.

Comment: Its data type is date. Why should i convert? 
Result should come with out using any function. 
Issue is related to indexing on that column that for sure.
I need some to help me to debug where is the problem.
I do not need help on writing the query in different way & get my result. That I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You have the table as a date, but is it a date or date/time.  May be failing on EXACT?

How about changing your where clause to

```
where TRCD_DATE >='2018-01-01' AND TRCD_DATE < '2018-01-02'
```

So you are getting anything from 12:00am (morning) all the way up to 11:59:59pm before the next day.  Don't try to convert the data column, that will prevent use of an index.

Comment: Its only date. No datetime.
Have give create table format of table in question.

Comment: @Punit, I DID see you had as date, but I think INTERNALLY it is doing something different.  Try the query as I have.  Do you get any results?

Comment: Its not working with TRCD_DATE >='2018-01-01' AND TRCD_DATE < '2018-01-02'
Still record count is zero.